Closed form expression for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} J_n^2(x) \cos(ny)$, where $J_n(x)$ is the Bessel function of order $n$
Anyone can find/calculate a closed form expression for the sum
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} J_n^2(x) \cos(ny),
$$
where
$J_n$ is the Bessel function?

Just solve for the sum in the addition formula (31) of Neumann 1867, p. 65 (also in Watson p. 128, or more conceptually Vilenkin 1968, formula (4) p. 209):
$$
J_0\left(2r\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\theta}2}\right)
= J_0(r)^2 + 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty J_n(r)^2\cos(n\theta).
$$
